# $p^a\mid f(v) \implies p^a\mid f(w)$ in $\mathbb Z[w]$

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, roots-of-unity

Let $p$ be a prime, $n$ a positive integer and $q=p^n$ a $p$- power. Let $w,v$ is a root of the $q,p$-th cyclotomic polynomial $Q_q,Q_p$, respectively. Let $f$ be a polynomial with coefficient in $\mathbb Z$.

Prove or disprove: "$p^a\mid f(v) \implies p^a\mid f(w)$"  in $\mathbb Z[w]$.

Edit: This question was an "iff" question, now it is "implies" question.

Moreover: $(p)=(1-v)^{p-1}$ in $\mathbb Z[v]$ and $(p)=(1-v)^{p^{n-1}(p-1)}$ in $\mathbb Z[w]$. That is, $p$ is totally ramified in both extension.

Comment: Do you mean that $f$  is a polynomial?

Comment: Yes, polynomial. Thanks.

Comment: For $p=2$, we can define a map: $0,1\rightarrow 1,-1$. But it is unnecessary. I will edit the question, one-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $i$ is coprime to $p$ this follows immediately from the fact that there is an automorphism $\sigma$ of the field $\Bbb{Q}(w)$ that maps $w\mapsto w^i$. Because $f\in\Bbb{Z}[x]$, we have
$$
f(w^i)=f(\sigma(w))=\sigma(f(w)).
$$
So if $f(w)=p^az$ for some number $z\in\Bbb{Z}[w]$ then $f(w^i)=p^a\sigma(z)$. Apply the inverse of $\sigma$ to get the other implication.

If $p\mid i$, then I think the claim is false. Let $f=Q_q$. Then $f(w)=0$ and thus divisible by $p^a$ for all $a$. OTOH $f(w^p)=p$ is divisible by $p^a$ only when $a=0,1$.